# Entity Framework 6 Create() vs new

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

What is the difference between adding an entity in these two ways?

```
MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
entities.myentities.Add(me);
```

vs

```
MyEntity me = entities.myentities.Create();
```

Do I still need to add "me" in the second example?  If so, is there some sort of advantage, one way or the other?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have a [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204921/createobject-vs-new-object-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
```

will create a new instance of `MyEntity`

```
MyEntity me = entities.myentities.Create();
```

will create a proxy wrapped instance of `MyEntity` (assuming your context is configured to create proxies)

> This proxy overrides some virtual properties of the entity to insert hooks for performing actions automatically when the property is accessed. For example, this mechanism is used to support lazy loading of relationships.

[from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx)

Comment: I hope I'm not stating the obvious, but I've had a bit more time to play around, and I've found that the {create} method allows me to use navigation properties (after I've added it) where as the {new} way doesn't.

Comment: @Yabbie the generated proxy gives you these benefits and is the better way of creating new instances

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you still need to add it. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.create?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) of the Create method:

> Creates a new instance of an entity for the type of this set. Note that this instance is NOT added or attached to the set.

Comment: Link is broken. Actual link: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.create

Comment: Hats off to you! You've managed to find a broken link in a post by someone whose hobby is to find [broken images](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f), [more broken images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332661/295232) and [broken links](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1506/15821) on the entire Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score -1):

```
MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
```

is equal to

```
MyEntity me = entities.myentities.Create();
```

Both of the above create a new instance of MyEntity but neither attach it to the DbSet represented by myentities.

The line

```
entities.myentities.Add(me)
```

attaches the instance to the DbSet, though you could use `Attach(me)` as well.

The "me" is required in the second example as you would be creating an instance of object without a reference to hold the object.

Comment: The created objects are equal only in very specific cases. Stating they are equal is very misleading or arguably just wrong. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406426/392626) and the corresponding official docs on [proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/proxies) or the [Create method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.create?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Comment: @Kissaki is right: that objects are equal only in certain cases.

Answer (score -1):

If you use entity inheritance, you can achieve nice polymorphism behaviour using Create() method because it always instantiate correct Entity (not generic one).
Example:

```
public DbSet GetDialDbSet(DialEnum type)
    {
        DbSet ret;
        switch (type)
        {
            default:
            case DialEnum.MAPPING_REASON:
                ret = DialMappingReasons; 
                break;

            case DialEnum.PROCESSING_INFORMATION:
                ret = DialProcessingInformation;
                break;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

and polymorphism usage:

```
 DialDerived entity = (DialDerived) Db.GetDialDbSet(type).Create()
```

Comment: This isn't necessary at all. Use `db.Set.BaseClass>().Create<SubClass>()`.

Comment: My example is about runtime conditions, not compile time. In that case your template solution is of course easier to use :)

Comment: The cast `(DialDerived)` makes it a compile-time condition.

Comment: How will you substitute SubClass as runtime variable?

Comment: Not. But your code eventually uses the derived type known at compile-time, so you might as well use a generic type parameter.

Comment: Use case: you need a method returning correct entity depending on ENUM value. What would you use?