# Generic Repository with Related Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a generic repository like this:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TObject> where TObject : class
{
    TObject Add(TObject t);
}

public class GenericRepository<TObject> : IGenericRepository<TObject> where TObject : class
{
    private readonly DbContext context;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public virtual TObject Add(TObject t)
    {
        context.Set<TObject>().Add(t);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return t;
    }
}
```

In my EF model I have Author and Book, which has a 1:N relationship. Author has a navigation property "Books" to Book and Book has "Author" to Author.

Then I have a generic service like this:

```
public class GenericService<TObject> : IGenericService<TObject> where TObject : class
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<TObject> context;

    public GenericService(IGenericRepository<TObject> ct)
    {
        context = ct;
    }

    public TObject Add(TObject data)
    {
        return context.Add(data);
    }
}
```

I have a unit test like this:

```
[TestMethod]

public void TestAdd()
{
    var b = new Book();
    b.AuthorId = 1;
    b.Name = "Test";
    b.ISBN = "1111";
    var service = new GenericService(new GenericRepository<Book>(new MyDbEntities()));
    var newBook = service.Add(b);
    Assert.AreEqual("Author1", newBook.Author.Name);
}
```

The problem is newBook.Author is null, which means the newly created object from the Add method doesn't have any of its related entities. I know one of the solutions for this kind of problem is to use .include() to include all the related entities but in my case, a generic respository, I don't see how this could be done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you instantiate the Book object. Instead of

```
var b = new Book();
```

you should do something like

```
var b = service.Create();
```

Where Create is a method that should return a new Book via EF:

```
context.Set<TObject>().Create();
```

Using create, EF will return a proxied object, so the navigation properties will be loaded after it is attached to the context, assuming all you references are ok and that your DatabaseContext uses Lazy Loading.

Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406426/1270813

By the way, what is the reason for a unit test that validates the lazy loading feature? Is it just for learning purposes? As a rule of thumb, you should test your code, not other frameworks.

Regards

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'll try .Create() to see if it works. Yes, I have the test here just to illustrate the problem I have. My real test is using Moq to test the logic, not the framework itself. Thank you again.

Comment: But I don't see a way for me to use Create() in my generic service class. Or I'll have to create a service specific for the Book type and assign all its attribute values on the proxy object that Create() returns?

Comment: You need to add that method to both your service class and your generic repository (the service finally has to call the repository.Create, who has access to EF). That's the only way you can have access to the Entity Framework Create() method. After the class is added to the db context, Entity Framework will start to attach the existing objects using lazy loading