# After upgrading EntityFramework some foreign key reference are not loaded anymore

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've recently updated from EF4 to EF6 (database-first). 
After many changes here and there, everything seems like working again as before.

Unfortunately, now I'm facing a really weired issue.

I have three simplyfied tables (`Movie`, `Director`, `Genre`). Each with a unique key (`Id`) of type `Guid`.

A movie has two foreign keys. One to `Director`, one to `Genre`.

Now, adding a new movie (director and genre already existing)

```
var movie = new Movie
{
    Name = "The Hobbit",
    DirectorId = Guid.Parse("c3c7606d-35f8-4de4-b7af-89ab19761dc4"),
    GenreId = Guid.Parse("e19e304e-2567-4771-b842-962c067b5565")
};

dbContext.Movie.Add(movie);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

As of coming from EF4, lazy loading is enabled.

When checking `movie.Director` I get the correct `Director`-entity. However, `movie.Genre` is always `null`.

I've already checked the FK-constraints at database, the generated edmx, classes and whatever I've found so far. At all, I could not figure out what is causing this behaviour.

**Side note: This is just a simplified example. The real project has more than 80 tables with much more relations.**

**Edit #1**

The classes `Movie`, `Genre` and `Director`

```
public partial class Movie
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Movie()
    {
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.Guid DirectorId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid GenreId { get; set; }

    public virtual Director Director { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
}

public partial class Director
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Director()
    {
        this.Movie = new HashSet<Movie>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
}

public partial class Genre
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Genre()
    {
        this.Movie = new HashSet<Movie>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
}
```

So. There is really nothing special about the generated code.

**Edit #2** (@gabriel comment)

```
var moviedId = Guid.Parse("de0eca49-eae7-4583-b2e7-0003c148db99");
var theMovie = dbContext.Movie.Single(m => m.Id == moviedId);
var theMovieInclude = dbContext.Movie.Include(m => m.Genre).Single(m => m.Id == moviedId);
```

Both objects have the property loaded correctly.

**Edit #3**

When using

```
var movie = dbContext.Set<Movie>().Create();

movie.Name = "The Hobbit";
movie.DirectorId = Guid.Parse("c3c7606d-35f8-4de4-b7af-89ab19761dc4");
movie.GenreId = Guid.Parse("e19e304e-2567-4771-b842-962c067b5565");

dbContext.Movie.Add(movie);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

instead, `movie.Genre` is now correctly set.

I don't understand why `movie.Director` is set using `new Movie()`, but `movie.Genre` is not.
Could anyone explain this?

In my understanding (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8205350/615288) question), no references should be loaded until attaching when using `new Movie()`instead of `dbContext.Set<Movie>().Create()`. But there are (at least some) references loaded.

Comment: I know it has already been a huge work but you could also change from dbfirst to codefirst (usually the code generator works fine so you only need to check if everything's still working). Could you please post some code (the movie class and the query for retrieve data)?

Comment: Unfortunately, changing to codefirst is not an option. The query for retrieving data is already shown. Looking in the `Locals` windows is enough to see, that `movie.Genre` is `null`. Will add code for `Movie`

Comment: is the entity stored in the table with the right Genre id?

Comment: @gabriel: Yes. The foreign key-values are existing and correct. The database would not allow insert when the FK is not existing at all. But, true. I've also checked this just to be sure ;)

Comment: Just making sure, can you retrieve it using Single while explicitly specifying the relational properties in the include?

Comment: @gabriel: See my edited questsion (Edit #2)

Comment: I don't see `Genre` in the `Movie` class. How is it defined? Also, *eager loading is enabled* doesn't make sense. I think you mean lazy loading.

Comment: @GertArnold: I've added the missing properties and yes, I meant lazy loading.

Comment: OK, so both can be loaded lazily (`virtual`). According to your second edit `Genre` actually does. So when exactly don't you see `Genre`?

Comment: @GertArnold: After adding/inserting a new `Movie` the relation to `Genre` is `null`, but for `Director` there is an object of type `Director` (the FK entry).

Comment: Please see my `Edit #3`. It is now working, but I don't get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: 
Somewhere earlier in the context of this issue (the question was just a simplified example), the related `Genre`-entity was already loaded into `dbContext`, e.g. for fetching the Id for the name 'Horror'.

At all, this `Genre` will then be mapped to the new `Movie` as of it's already existing/loaded in `dbContext`.